# Ideal which is maximal with respect to the property that it does not contain the set S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Question

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $S$ be a subset of $R$. Prove that there exists an ideal that is maximal by inclusion with respect to the property that it does not contain the set $S$.

I think it can be shown similar to the Krull's theorem by Zorn's lemma.

[Here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/the-set-of-prime-ideals-of-a-commutative-ring-contains-inclusion-minimal-elements/) is similar question.

But in this case, I can't show that the union of chain element does not contain S. There are insufficient condition.

With this condition, it can be shown that there exists such an ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not true.  First of all, it trivially fails if $S=\emptyset$ or $S=\{0\}$, since in those cases every ideal contains $S$.  But it can fail less trivially as well.  For instance, let $R$ be any non-Noetherian valuation ring and let $S\subset R$ be a non-finitely generated ideal.  If $M\subset R$ were maximal with the property that $S\not\subseteq M$, then $M\subset S$, since the ideals of $R$ are totally ordered.  But then let $s\in S\setminus M$, and consider the ideal $(s)$.  We must have $M\subset (s)$, and so by maximality of $M$ we have $(s)=S$.  This contradicts the assumption that $S$ is not finitely generated.

What is true is that if $S\subseteq R\setminus\{0\}$, then there exists an ideal that is maximal with respect to the property that it is *disjoint* from $S$.  This is straightforward to prove by Zorn's lemma.